# Can hosted GitHub Pages websites accept file uploads?

Tags: github-pages

I would like to create a simple website that accepts a text file upload for a small project that parses the text.  Is this possible to do with GitHub Pages?  I haven't found anything that addresses this functionality so I am wondering if it is possible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen [in this issue](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/408), there is no server side configuration or execution with GitHub Pages, so no.

The only workaround is [`rafrex/spa-github-pages`: Single Page Apps for GitHub Pages](https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages), a lightweight solution for deploying single page apps with [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/). You can easily deploy a React single page app with [React Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) `<BrowserRouter />`.
But that might not include what you are looking for.